# Matlab equivalent code of the following equation

Tags: matlab, loops, math

I have an equation for which I am trying to write a code in Matlab, but I am not sure if my code is right. The equation is as follows:

[image: Equation]

Where I think the iteration is over the superscript i.e. k, k+1 etc and the dimensions are marked by subscripts m, n, n'. The notations are not well defined in the literature so I think this is how it should be.

My code segment for this equation is as follows:

```
c_n = [1,2,3,4]';     % c^(0)_n (nx1) vector
K = 50;
d = [0.5,0.9]';

for k = 1:1:K
 c_n = c_n.*((sum(A_mn'*d/(sum(A_mn*c_n,2)),2))./sum(A_mn',2)) ;
end
```

Is this code correct for the above equation?. The summations in the equation are confusing me.

Comment: We need more insight as to the dimensionality of the variables you've listed here.  Are `c` and `d` vectors? Is `A` a matrix?

Comment: yes `c` and `d` are vectors, `A` is a matrix (mxn). `A^T` is just transpose of `A`.

Comment: These are all basic matrix operations, no need for sum. That is why they have a sum over `A^T` instead of the same sum over just `A` with the indices transposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `A` is a matrix with `m` rows and `n` columns, then the sum [image: \sum_{m} (A^T)_{nm}] is just the sum of the `n`th row in `AT`. This is the same as the corresponding sum of the `n`th column in `A`: [image: \sum_{m} A_{mn}]. The matrix multiplication it represents works out nicer with the transpose because matrix multiplications are just sums of weighted rows.

Similarly, [image: \sum_{n'} A_{mn'}c_{n'}] is the `m`th row of `A`, weighted element-wise by by `c`.

We can assume that `c` and `d` are **column** vectors of size `n` and `m`, respectively. (`d'` will be represented by just plain `d` in the code). In that case, most of the operations can be reduced to matrix operations:

1. [image: \sum_{n'} A_{mn'}c_{n'}] is just the matrix product `A * c`, which yields a column vector of size `m`.
2. [image: \frac{d'_m}{\sum_{n'} A_{mn'}c_{n'}}] then becomes the element-wise ratio `d ./ (A * c)`, also of size `m`.
3. The ratio is used to scale the elements of the sum of `AT` in the numerator, making it the matrix product `A.' * (d ./ (A * c))` of size `n`.
4. Each element of that is scaled by [image: \sum_{m} (A^T)_{nm}], which can be represented by either `A.' * ones(m, 1)` or `sum(A, 1).'`, so the final matrix product is just `c .* (A.' * (d ./ (A * c)) ./ sum(A, 1).')`.

You can pre-calculate `sum(A, 1).'`, call it `e` to get the following:

```
c = [1; 2; 3; 4];
d = [0.5; 0.9];
A = ... some 2x4 matrix;
e = sum(A, 1).';
k = 50;

for i = 1 : k
    c = c .* (A.' * (d ./ (A * c)) ./ e);
end
```

If you want to retain the intermediate values of `c` for each `k`, you can allocate a matrix of size `n, k + 1` and fill that in with each column representing a new iteration of `c`:

```
c = zeros(4, 51);
c(:, 1) = [1; 2; 3; 4];
for i = 1 : k
    c(:, k + 1) = c(:, k) .* (A.' * (d ./ (A * c(:, k))) ./ e);
end
```

Comment: My code seems to return the same output as yours. But, yours is certainly cleaner and efficient. Thanks for the detailed explanation as well.

Comment: @radk. I suspect that your implementation is correct as well.

Comment: @radk, if this answer was helpful, you should select it.